# How to calculate the year to specific date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an Excel table like this, which I eventually load into Power BI:

[image]

And for each month, I calculate the YTD average value.
[image]

So, for example, the YTD value for Male at March is `AVERAGE(4+43+32) = 26`

How can I create a measure so that I can work out the year to specific date (say 1st Jan 2023 to 1st March 2023) average value and present it like below?

I.e. What would the DAX calculation look like in order to get the result of the above table within Power BI? How do I make it so that it gets the average of Jan for month Jan, average of Jan and Feb for month Feb, average of Jan, Feb and Mar for month March etc.?

[image]

Comment: Add a Calendar slicer to your report.

Comment: @Mik What would the DAX calculation look like in order to get the result of the 2nd table within Power BI? How do I make it so that it gets the average of Jan for month Jan, average of Jan and Feb for month Feb, average of Jan, Feb and Mar for month March?

Answer (score 1):

```
YTD average = 
AVERAGEX(
    FILTER('Table','Table'[Date]<=EARLIER('Table'[Date])
        &&'Table'[Gender]=EARLIER('Table'[Gender])),
    [People])
```

[image]